# images not displaying when i hung my webcite on 000webhost.com

Tags: html, web

SO I designed this cite for my class when I view it locally the logo shows up the image below my title but the background never des I still decided to host it on 000webhost.com and so I included the images in the same folder but now when I view the hosted version neither the logo nor the background shows up I adjusted the file path to match the folder on my hosting cite but still no progress.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>WELCOME TO MY IT461 HOME PAGE!</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            background-image: src("/public_html/OIP (6).jpeg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        p {
            text-align: justify;
        }

        .image {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .links {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        hr {
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin: 30px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>WELCOME TO MY IT461 HOME PAGE!</h1>

    <div class="image">
        <img src="/public_html/OIP (5).jpeg" alt="ODU Logo" width="300">
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try to access the image directly via a browser to make sure the file is accessible? Its been a while but I remember a free hosting service making images private by default (similar to code files) until set 'public' or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are in same folder as `index.[html|php]` than remove `/public_html` from images URL's:

```
    <div class="image">
        <img src="/OIP (5).jpeg" alt="ODU Logo" width="300">
    </div>
```

---

Since `public_html` usually contains website root, I assume you have this structure:

```
public_html/
 |- index.html
 |- OIP (6).jpeg
 |- OIP (5).jpeg
```

and in `src` you must put accessible URL, not path on server. Simplest way to check:

- Open Developer Tools (Usually F12)
- Navigate to *Network* tab
- Filter to show only images requests
- Reload page
- Check URL that browser tries to access that fails - figure out what you need to change for it to be accessible (usually change URL)

Comment: Yes, thank you were correct to assume the structure i removed the folder name the logo image finally appeared but unfortunately the background image is still not visible. this is what i have down for t                                   background-image: src("/OIP (6).jpeg");

Comment: Have you checked network tab? Does loading this image fails?

Comment: @TobiOlayinka oh, I see. Its not `src` in CSS, its `url`. Always inspect your elements when something not working. Browser devTools should tell you that rules is invalid